# How to get items of a wikipedia list article using wikipedia api?

Tags: wikipedia-api

How to get items of a Wikipedia list using Wikipedia api. Eg all sports listed on:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sports

Comment: Have a look at [Wikipedia's API page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page)

Comment: couldn't find anything on accessing items of a wikipedia list

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a parameter to set the response format.

```
format=json
```

Comment: I know how to get response in JSON format for any query on the api, I am asking how to get json formatted list of individual sports from List_of_sports article

Comment: @timmaktu then your question is more about JSON parsing than the API itself? I'd suggest updating it so it's clearer